# Android Play Billing Library: get subscription expiry?

Tags: android, play-billing-library

I'm struggling to find the expiry time of an in app subcription using **only** the [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html).

On a Purchase object I can get the purchase time (getPurchaseTime()) and use that to calculate the expiry time (as I know which period the SKU stands for). The problem is that is seems that the purchase time doesn't get renewed on subscription renewal.

I need help getting the expiry date of a subscription. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the proposed duplicate. This question is regarding the Billing Library from Google, which is not the case in the other post.